# Laravel model all() function is not working as intended

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model {

     protected $table = 'contacts';
    //

}
```

And in the controller action

```
$c= Contact::all();
```

I am getting the "`Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`" error.
**Error detail:**

```
FatalErrorException in ContactController.php line 9:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Contact' not found
```

The table "`contacts`" exists in the database.
What thing I am missing? Whats wrong here?

Comment: check your log file found under storage/logs

Comment: @KhanShahrukh, check I have added the error detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell your controller where your model is if it is in route of your project then on the top of your controller add

```
use App\Contact;
```

Or you may also define it every time

```
$c = App\Contact::all();
```

also in your model no need to define a table until it is not different from the plural model name. If your model name is Contact, laravel on its own query contacts table, you should define the table name if the model name is Contact and the table name is somethingElse.

Comment: Still not working, getting this error:
FatalErrorException in ContactController.php line 9:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Contact' not found

Answer (score 3):

Don't use

`$c= Contact::all();`

Instead use

`$c = \App\Contact::all()`

or

```
$c = new \App\Contact;
$c->all();
```

This is all that you have to use.

**UPDATE**: Just after digging in the concepts of OOP, I found this:

```
<?php
    use \App\Contact;

    var_dump(Contact::all());
```